# How to reduce the number of cert validation requests... (IE is killing me slowly)

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, certificate, xampp

On a customer's internal network, I can make a request to my SSL site using IE6 SP1 (on Win2K) and see one cert validation requests, but if I use IE6 SP2 (on XP) 13 separate cert validation requests get fired off.  Needless to say, this slows down my page load a lot.

Firefox loads the page just fine with no unnecessary cert validation requests.

The server is Apache running a pretty new lampp stack.  All the server certificate / CA chain configurations seem to be fine (users can authenticate w/ trusted certs, the system can communicate to other systems with that server cert, etc.)

Is there anything I can do from a configuration standpoint?  Any other ideas at all?

Comment: Are these bona-fide certificates from a recognised CA such as Verisign or Thawte?

Comment: Could you trace down the 13 cert requests, to which host are they giong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that "upgrade IE" is off the table, right?  You're probably trying to find a way to support IE 6.0, SP2, with XP, so your users can use this version.

OK... one thought is trying to mess with the SSL configuration.  As I remember, SSL has a number of settings that can be used and perhaps you can change one of them on your server and get a different behavior.  It might be worth it to research what's happening during the [SSL Handshake](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6156-10/contents.htm#1041640) on the working and not-working versions of IE 6.0.  I favor Ethereal, a free network traffic watching tool that will capture the SSL.  It can't decrypt it easily, but you can at least see the first few messages that happen in the clear.   It might give an inkling into why all these validation requests are coming in.